# Cannot align san-serif font to the very edge of H1 tag

Tags: html, css, fonts

Odd problem which makes me suspect I'm missing something simple. Any ideas on the following:

I have a H1 tag with a sans-serif font (loaded from Google fonts) and if I give it a background-color you can see the text isn't aligning to the left of the containing tag:

[image: Small gap between the starting H and the left-hand side]

If I add a serif font you can see taht it does behave how I need it to, the text is up against the left hand side. When I turn it on/off in dev tools it is simply adding/removing the serifs:

[image]

There are no styles applied to the H1 other than a font-weight. Tried resetting my margins but to no avail.

I can set a nagtive margin but that won't work for all resolutions.

Comment: I believe the problem is in the font itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in the font glyph itself, so no way to circumvent it easily via CSS unless you edit the font itself. See the following screenshots.

Serif:
[image]

Sans-serif:
[image: Sans Serif]

Tool for reference: http://nodebox.github.io/opentype.js/glyph-inspector.html

Answer (score 0):

The kerning will be off. It occupies a set width, irrespective of whether the letter is at the edge. Free fonts are known for it. The best way to combat this is to use a different font.

Comment: The kerning isn't off, the letterform just doesn't butt right up against the character's bounding box – you may find that this will be the case with most typefaces.